# Mocking a helper function in django view test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a view function that initiates user login requests

it looks something like this:

```
def initiate_login(request):
    # get request parameters
    return check_user_and_send_otp(login_id)
```

The request is then processed by another function

```
def check_user_and_send_otp(login_id):
    # check if user exits
    return send_otp_to_user(phone_number)
```

And then another function

```
def send_otp_to_user(phone_number):
    # sends a message to user
    return response
```

The problem is while testing my code, I don't want to send messages to a phone number while testing.

My login test function looks somewhat like this, is it possible to mock it without changing my code?

```
    def test_login_initiator(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.login_url, data=self.login_data, content_type="application/json", **self.headers)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

> All these functions that were called by others are located in seperate modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do would be use something like magic mock and structure the code into proper classes so that we can create mock objects for each of them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually receive the message on a physical phone, you can use online sms receivers. Check out this [blog](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/top-10-sites-receive-sms-online-without-phone).

Additionally, you can send messages through other free online services like Way2sms. You just have to google them up. To do this from within Python, you need to use web parsing using urllib2/requests and beautifulsoup, which is a totally new question.

Or you can skip this function by simply commenting out the message sender code or returning true from the function.

If you wanna live dangerously, think about making a config file which can help you to make switches that tell whether to execute something or not.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, the send_otp function actually calls a third party API to send an SMS to user's phone and the `response` is if the message was successful, I can post the actual code snippet if you like.This was just to simplify things.

Comment: Oh, so basically, you're trying to check if the text messages are being successfully sent to a phone but don't want to actually send out a message right?

Comment: I just want the function to return true (that the message is sent) but actually not send a message. It's like overwriting with something like `return True`

Comment: commenting out the could do the trick for me, but is it a good practice to do so while running unit tests? and if someone else runs my tests, he might not remember to comment it out.

Comment: You can always include in the documentation about what to comment and what not to, so it won't be a problem with other people using the module. Commenting a code out simply tells the compiler to skip this part, so it is a good practice. The only problem you might face is when you lose the source code and try to get it back through decompiling a pyc file. And you kinda answered your own question. `return True` is valid.

Comment: Thanks, I will mention that in the documentation :)

Comment: If this was helpful and successful answered your query, accept the answer I edited so it can be useful for others in the future.